# Spring/Struts 2 Configuration - any dummies' guide?

Tags: java, spring, struts2

I'm a beginner in practical real-world java programming. I don't really understand these basic things in Spring - using it for jdbc calls (without any ORM), mail api, configuring logger. I think, I got a bit scared with the configurations (long, time-consuming) that're required to get these things working.

Can anyone recommend dummies guide to get started with Spring/Struts 2 configurations or some practical notes from your day-to-day experiences on how to understand configuring part well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html

Its not for dummies, but everything you need is in there.  You can copy and paste  a lot of it to get going (like configuration).  Since you don't want ORM, JDBCTemplate is your friend.

Comment: a very useful link, thank you hvgotcodes! I'm also looking for links explaining a simple working project that makes use of mail api and logger along with jdbc templates.. maybe I am asking too much! :)

Comment: do you want to build something or just learn? Assuming the former, I suggest you start by implementing an application that uses JdbcTemplate, with tests.  Then just google for a log4j and mail api tutorial when ready.  But start with one things, get a sense for it, then move to the next thing.

One more thing: write tests.  Spring provides some great utility classes for testing db methods.  They will role your tests back at the end of every test so your changes go away, which is usually what you want...

Comment: I wanted to build a little appln and have successfully built it, thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

AppFuse is a great webapp template project that uses Struts2/Spring.

It pretty much has everthing  you would want - go through the quickstart guide at http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart.